# error in adding new view page for Yii2 website

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I just recently came back in Yii2 and php. What I'm trying to do is add new view page in my website using Yii2 named login.php but it seems like it is not read properly. I added actionLogin in my controller and also login.php is visible in the views folder. Did I miss a thing?

I am using MainController.php for displaying it

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Basic;
use app\models\BasicSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * BasicController implements the CRUD actions for Basic model.
 */
class MainController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Basic models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index', [
        ]);
    }

    public function actionLogin()
    {
        return $this->render('login', [
        ]);
    }
}
```

login.php looks like this:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;


$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Basics');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

?>

LOGIN
```

[image]

Comment: what is the directory path of login view page

Comment: it looks like this `view/main/login.php`

Comment: your path is correct, but i can see url in your browser as `127.0.0.1/login.php`, seems that you are missing your controller name due to improper configuration. It must look  like this `127.0.0.1/project_name/main/login`

Comment: Thanks! solved the problem. My bad, i forgot the structure

Comment: your welcome. glad to help you :)